# Combining 2 scopes to get single scope that has A,B,A,B,A,B order from the original scopes (Like zip.flatten would to an Array)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a rails controller, i am looking to zip 2 scopes together, but want to keep them as AR:Relations, not Arrays. The scope is filtered on a few params before it gets sorted, and its in the sort I would like to split the scope and then zip it. For example I would like to have all Items filtered by the params, then split 'Featured' Items from normal Items and have the sort return [Featured, Normal, Featured, Normal, Featured....]

So given something like...

```
scope = Items.all
scope = scope.build_search(params)

scope_featured = scope.featured
scope_normal = scope.non_featured

@results = scope_featured.zip(scope_normal).flatten # This of course will return an array not an AR:Relation
```

I am wondering about plucking the ids of the scopes and ziping them and then using `Item.find([ids])` but it does not seem to be the most efficient. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You mean `@results = scope_featured + scope_normal` ? (But it should be an Arel and not Array ?)

Comment: I want the scopes to merge in an alternating sort, not just one infront of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the best solution, but I found *a* solution using row_number in postgres and union.

```sql
select *, 'items1' as table_name, row_number() over () as rownum
  from "items" where key = 'some_key'
union
select *, 'items2' as table_name, row_number() over () as rownum
  from "items" where key <> 'some_key'
order by rownum, table_name
```

select twice from the same table using your 2 scopes, add row numbers, union them together and order the result according to row number. The constant table_name is there to ensure that one of the queries always comes first on the same row number so they indeed alternate.

Converting this to `Arel` left as an exercise to the reader.